# PHP: How to change date() function to Central Time (-6)

Tags: php, date

I'm using the date function to be displayed for each of my new posts in a CMS.
However, I do not know how to change that value according to my timezone, which is [UTC−06:00](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%E2%88%9206:00).

This is how I'm doing it:

```
    $p['time'] = date("F j, Y, h:i a");
    $time = $p['time'];
```

And this is how it looks:

```
August 24, 2011, 4:39 pm
```

Right now if the current time is 10:39 AM, the $time reported should be 4:39PM. I need to get rid of those extra 6 hours somehow.

Comment: date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+6 Hours')) or maybe date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-18 Hours')) depending on your server timezone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try calling [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) before all your time handling.

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/Belize");
```

[Timezones reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)